# Imprimir una variable de PHP a otro PHP

Tags: php, html5

en mi archivo index.php tengo lo siguiente, donde la variable $error viene de validacion.php que contiene el código

```
<div class="mensaje">

<strong class="error">

<?php echo $error;?></strong>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo de validacion.php

```
 if(isset($filas['id-cargo'])==2){ 
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    else{
    ?>
        <?php
            $error="Usuario incorrecto";
    }
```

Comment: Nos muestras 2 archivos, pero donde los unes? osea donde necesitas que la variable se pase a otro archivo?

Comment: Necesito que la variable $error que esta en validacion.php se muestre dentro del <div class="mensaje"> </div> que se encuentra en el index.php

Comment: Puedes usar un tercer archivo y llamarlos con Include, has intentado eso?

Comment: Es que en si, el index.php es un formulario, en donde hay un DIV que quiero que ahi adentro me muestre ela variable $error que se encuentra en validación.php dentro de un if,  tal vez seria algo absurdo hacer un tercer archivo, corregime si me equivoco, pero si me podes dar un ejemplo en código

Comment: y el validacion.php no lo puedes incluir en el index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
<?php
if(isset($error)){
echo '
<div class="mensaje">
     <strong class="error">
     '.$error.' </strong>
</div>';
}
?>
```

o así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
echo '
<div class="mensaje">
     <strong class="error">
     '.$_GET['error'].' </strong>
</div>';
}
?>
```

**Código de validacion.php**

```
if(isset($filas['id-cargo'])==2){ 
    header("location: index.php");
}else{
    ?>
    <?php
    $error="Usuario incorrecto";
    header("location: index.php?error=$error");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió la segunda con el método GET

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, si la respuesta resolvió tu problema, no olvides marcarla como correcta. saludos!